# Movie about a glove with blades that kills people

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie when I was a child (late 90s, early 2000s, but movie might be 80s or 90s)

The movie is about a metallic (or other rigid material) glove that lives on its own. There is a scene with a boy under his bed sheet with his dinosaur plushie and at some point that plushie gets sliced up.

There is another scene where said glove lies on the backseat of a car and a man is driving it. I don't know whether the glove manages to kill the driver.

There is a movie with Michael Caine where he loses his hand but I am quite certain the hand is artificial.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Would it be correct to assume this was a live-action, colour movie?

Comment: Its a live action and colour movie, yes. The said dino plushie was green iirc

Comment: One of the Freddie Krueger movies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you are looking for Wes Cravens "New Nightmare" released in 1994. In the beginning Nancy (Heather Langenkamp) has a nightmare in which Freddy's prop glove does move around and kill two people and scratches her husband on his finger. He has the same scratch when she wakes up. Later in the movie her husband is killed by the glove after he falls asleep while driving. Michael Caine has nothing to do with this series unfortunately .

Comment: And the plush toy?

Comment: That's his stuffed dino named Rex. He gets the stuffing shredded out of him sadly

Comment: I think thats it. I was sure it was a single glove and not Freddy. I'll accept your answer when i watched the movie and am certain :)